# issue with fileReader in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to create a simple lwc which uses input type=file and then would read data from the text file. However, reader.onload or reader.onloadend aren't fired at all..

Below is the code:

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="File Upload">
        <div>
            <input type="file" name="fileUpload"><br/>
            <input type='button' value='Process' onclick={handleUpload} />
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class FileUpload extends LightningElement {
    handleUploadFinished(){
        var file = this.template.querySelector("input[type='file']");
        console.log('file : ' ,file);

        var reader = new FileReader();
        
        reader.onloadend = function(){
            console.log('reader loaded');
        }
    }
}
```

What's wrong here? Console inside reader.onloadend isn't printed at all, also tried reader.onload but that doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are not even calling the `handleUploadFinished` method. Use the `onchange` event handler to capture the file input. (Note i have demonstrated for one file but you can do for multiple as well if you wish, just note that apex heap will blow if you use large files.)

You can try the below code

**Component html**

**The Component JS Controller**

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class FileUpload extends LightningElement {

      fileName;
      filesUploaded;
      base64Data = '';

      constructor() {
        super();
     }

    handleFileChange(event) {
      if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
        this.filesUploaded = event.target.files[0];
        this.fileName = event.target.files[0].name;
       }
    }
    
    handleClick() {
     const toBase64 = (file) =>
     new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
        reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
    });
    toBase64(this.filesUploaded)
    .then((result) => {
        const base64Constant = 'base64,';
        const base64Value =
        result.indexOf(base64Constant) + base64Constant.length;
        this.base64Data = result.substring(base64Value);
    });
  }
}
```

check here for the demo of this code in [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/pCRDegTUd/11/edit)